# What is the coversation log URL for IBM Chatbot assistant?

Tags: ibm-watson, watson-conversation

What is the url to see the conversation logs?

I have tried https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/assistant/api/v1/workspaces/{workspace_id}/logs?version=2018-09-20&filter=(response_timestamp<2019-01-31T04:00:00.000Z)

but I am not able to see the input from the user.

Comment: What command did you try? How did you authenticate? Please provide more details

Comment: I am trying to view the conversation logs based on the url only, i will then implement in on a asp.net web application. I am currently stuck on building the web application, hence, i am trying to see if I am able to see the conversation logs when I enter the url......

Answer (score 0):

The URL is correct, but the params may not. The brackets in the filter param are not needed, and the whole filter param has to be url escaped. Furthermore, you have to authenticate to use this endpoint.

```
curl -u "apikey:{apikey}" "https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/assistant/api/v1/workspaces/{workspace_id}/logs?version=2018-09-20"
```

See [here](https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/assistant#list-log-events-in-a-workspace) for details. Furthermore, the [Botium CLI](https://github.com/codeforequity-at/botium-cli) has a command to automate the download of the conversation log, for example:

```
botium-cli import watson-logs --watsonfilter "response_timestamp>=2018-10-21, response_timestamp<2018-10-29"
```

Comment: Is there a way I can filter by dates? and is there a way to view the conversations solely based on the url? sorry im new to ibm watson...

Comment: "Url only" won't work as it requires authentication. Watson documentation linked above contains information about what filters are supported - date filter is among them, of course. You can see it in action above with the "response_timestamp" filter.